# Is it possible to upload android app with new key on google play

Tags: android, flutter

my app is published on the play store, its build in Iconic Cordova. Now I have built my app in flutter. I want to publish it as an update of the old app. I have lost the signed key of the old app. Is it possible to upload the app with new signed key. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need same key to update the app, if you loss it, you can't update the app on the Play Store.

Comment: You can’t update without key.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible and now you'll need to change the package name too and your app will be treated as totally different app. This is Google's play Policy.